# Single URLSession for all requests versus per request, performance

Tags: objective-c, performance, urlsession

In a legacy project which has both ObjC and Swift Code I noticed that for each request a new session was created:

```
-(void)sendRequest {
// Some configuration

// New session is created for every request
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
[session dataTaskWithRequest:self.request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse *_Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
// Doing something with response
}
}
```

As per the information shared in past WWDC videos and answer over here: [New NSURLSession for every DataTask overkill?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/84663), I noticed that this is an anti-pattern and should be avoided. In it's place we should use a single URLSession for all requests:

```
-(void)sendRequest:(NSURLReqest *)request {
// Some configuration

// 
[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse *_Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
// Doing something with response
}
}
```

Please note that at server HTTP 1.1 is configured for the rest APIs.

As per my understanding whenever we create a new session it is equivalent to creating a new TCP connection, since there is a handshake involved at the beginning for each new TCP connection that will add latency so ideally we should use same URLSession for each request.

In order to validate it I started profiling both the implementations using Instruments for a scenario where after login we are invoking 50 APIs most of which are returning json in response, 10 returning image data.

Here is my observation:

1. There is slight improvement in time taken by each request
2. Whenever we use one session per request, internally OS creates parallel connections so it achieves identical results when compared to the single session used for all requests
3. If we are directly serializing image using URLSessionDataTask it takes less time versus using URLSessionDownloadTask

Based on 2nd and 3rd observation it appears to be a bad choice in my case. Am I missing anything over here?

Comment: If you launch too many calls in parallels, you might overuse your resources, as there might be creating too many threads. While using a single URLSession, you can limit the parallel calls (with `httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost` for instance).

Comment: @Larme unfortunately it is difficult to convince stakeholders unless it is a performance win.

Comment: Do a test with more than 10 requests, like 100 and on real device. On "old" ones too if possible. You might see then the differences.